# Hatching a smooth cycle

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

I'd like to hatch a smooth circle, but everything I try ends up getting some weird part. My code is

```
\documentclass[tikz,border={5pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=1+0.1*rnd;}]
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
            \path[draw,semithick, name path=curve] plot[domain=0:350,smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What generates is

[image]

But I would like it to be hatch inside the shape, like

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, then just put a pattern into the path:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=1+0.1*rnd;}]
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\path[pattern={Lines[angle=45, distance={5pt/sqrt(2)}, line width=2pt]}, pattern color=blue] 
    plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(It might look a bit distorted, but this is due to rounding errors. The above code results in a picture which looks actually fine when printed.)

---

You can also use `path picture` to place any picture as "background" to the path:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=1+0.1*rnd;}]
\pgfmathsetseed{1}
\path[path picture={
    \node at (path picture bounding box.center) {\includegraphics[width=5cm]{pattern.jpg}};
}] 
    plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, there is no need to load the `color` package, since `tikz` loads `xcolor` already.